# Updating button view after async task listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I'm currently parsing data from a web server "A" into a Listview using Lazy Adapter. Each row has a button that when selected sends the data in that row to web server "B" using a separate AsyncTask class. I'm using a callback on the asynctask with a onTaskComplete to update the activity. Which works just fine, I get a correct response from the server.

My question is how do I update the button image depending upon the response from the server. So for example if the response from the server equals 1 update the button image else if the response equals 0 do not change the button image.  I'm just not sure how to pass the response from the activity to the adapter to update button image. Any advice would be appreciated.

MY CODE:

Adapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    RowHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
        holder = new RowHolder();
        holder.a_refid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.a_refid);
        holder.a_a_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.a_name);
        holder.a_location = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.a_location);
        holder.checkin = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.a_checkin);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RowHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> locList;
    locList = data.get(position);
    holder.a_refid.setText(locList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFID));
    holder.a_name.setText(locList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));
    holder.a_location.setText(locList.get(MainActivity.KEY_LOCATION));        

    HashMap<String, String> details = dbh.getUserDetails();
    final String useruid = details.get("uid");
    Log.d("UID", useruid);

    final HashMap<String, String> finallocList = locList;
    holder.a_refid.setTag(finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFID));
    holder.a_name.setTag(finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFID));
    holder.a_location.setTag(finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFID));

    //Check In Button
    holder.checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle("Check-in to: " + finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));
            builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Check-In", "Anonymous Check-In",  
          "Cancel"},
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                            // of the selected item
                            switch (which) {
                                case 0:
                                    new    
        AcheckPro(activity).execute(finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_REFID), useruid,  
        finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME), 
        finallocList.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));
                                    Log.d("Check In Process", String.valueOf(useruid));
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, "button 2 clicked",  
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, "button 3 clicked",  
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

AsyncTask Class

```
public class AcheckPro extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

private Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback;

public AcheckPro(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
    this.callback = (AsyncTaskCompleteListener)act;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    String refid = params[0];
    String uid = params[1];
    String name = params[2];
    String location = params[3];        

    JFunctions jFunctions = new JFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.checkInUser(refid, uid, name, location);
    return json;


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    super.onPostExecute(json);
    if (null != dialog && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    Log.d("JSON Object", String.valueOf(json));
    callback.onTaskComplete(json);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you share code which you've written when you get data from server?

Comment: @Carbongixxer Share your code ...so that we can help you

Comment: @PsyGik Added my code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by this logic

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button myButton;
boolean flag = false;
RelativeLayout rl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) new LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(flag){
            myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.record_button_pressed));
        }else{
            myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.record_button_normal));
        }

        rl.addView(myButton,params);

    }
```

And you can pass response to AdapterClass through it's constructor.

Comment: This answer does not address the Q which was specifically " I'm just not sure how to pass the response from the activity to the adapter to update button image.". It merely shows how a button can be changed when its clicked : this is not the same as updating the button after an async call back.